# Wordpress site with 200K posts SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with JOINs slow? Optimize for speed?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, optimization

I have a Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz, 24 cores / 32 GB ram server and freaks out on the queries from a site with 200 000 posts. Here are some of them:

`+--------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id     | User             | Host      | db                 | Command | Time | State        | Info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | Progress |
+--------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| 187729 | site_com      | localhost | site_com        | Query   |    2 | Sending data | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (436695) AND ( 
  wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (30)
            ) 
  AND 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (206,506,636,637,801,4237,4646,4647,4648)
) AND ( 
  wp_postmeta.post_id IS NULL 
  OR 
  ( mt1.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' AND mt1.meta_value = 'deleted' )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 45 |    0.000 |
| 187742 | site_com      | localhost | site_com        | Query   |    1 | Sending data | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (289150) AND ( 
  wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (30)
            ) 
  AND 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (79,308,674)
) AND ( 
  wp_postmeta.post_id IS NULL 
  OR 
  ( mt1.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' AND mt1.meta_value = 'deleted' )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 45                              |    0.000 |
| 187755 | site_com      | localhost | site_com        | Query   |    8 | Sending data | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (161366) AND ( 
  wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (30)
            )
) AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_Photo Source Domain' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'www.site1.com' ) 
  AND 
  ( 
    mt1.post_id IS NULL 
    OR 
    ( mt2.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' AND mt2.meta_value = 'deleted' )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 9         |    0.000 |
| 187787 | site_com      | localhost | site_com        | Query   |    3 | Sending data | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (442261) AND ( 
  wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (30)
            )
) AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_Photo Source Domain' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'site2.com' ) 
  AND 
  ( 
    mt1.post_id IS NULL 
    OR 
    ( mt2.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' AND mt2.meta_value = 'deleted' )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 9               |    0.000 |
| 187798 | site_com      | localhost | site_com        | Query   |    2 | Sending data | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (161180) AND ( 
  wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (30)
            )
) AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_Photo Source Domain' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'www.site1.com' ) 
  AND 
  ( 
    mt1.post_id IS NULL 
    OR 
    ( mt2.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' AND mt2.meta_value = 'deleted' )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 9         |    0.000 |
| 187845 | site_com      | localhost | site_com        | Query   |    5 | Sending data | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (160175) AND ( 
  wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (30)
            )
) AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_Photo Source Domain' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'www.site1.com' ) 
  AND 
  ( 
    mt1.post_id IS NULL 
    OR 
    ( mt2.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' AND mt2.meta_value = 'deleted' )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 13        |    0.000 |
| 187901 | site_com      | localhost | site_com        | Query   |    0 | Sending data | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (159918) AND ( 
  wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (30)
            )
) AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_Photo Source Domain' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'www.site1.com' ) 
  AND 
  ( 
    mt1.post_id IS NULL 
    OR 
    ( mt2.meta_key = '_Original Post ID' AND mt2.meta_value = 'deleted' )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 13        |    0.000 |
+--------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+`

I tried some functions messing with Wordpress, I tried adding post_id_meta_key index but that fails, too. Any ideas, guys? Greatly appreciated!! My server is now on 1000% cpu usage with load averages of 20-30 or more because of this site and mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress, in my opinion, has not been designed to handle more than a few thousand Posts.

- `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` requires (sort of) scanning all 200K rows to get the number.  Notice how search engines got away from saying "... out of 212,345" Posts long ago.  Maybe you should, too.
- `wp_postmeta` has inefficiencies that can be overcome.  See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248207/simple-sql-query-on-wp-postmeta-very-slow
- `OR` is inefficient, try to avoid it.

(There may be more that would help those queries.)

Comment: Looks like that helped. Thanks!! Always helpful, Rick!!

Comment: Check out this plugin by @RickJames and me. https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while but I was able to incredibly reduce the time for queries very similar to the one mentioned in the question by creating the index below:

```
CREATE INDEX post_id_meta_key ON wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key(191));
```

I found this by browsing a [Github issue comment posted](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/6706#issuecomment-424998742) for the Yoast plugin project

Hopefully it will help others with similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when there are lots of posts this part of the query becomes slow in itself already:

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1
```

Any additional where criteria only adds to the load, but this part can take several 10s of seconds or minutes or who knows how long.

In my experience adding foreign key constraints can help the DB to maintain faster way to relate two tables, so this may help to do:

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta
ADD CONSTRAINT wp_postmeta_wp_posts_FK
FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
REFERENCES wp_posts(ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This only made a 4x time speed up in my slow WP queries.

But this together with the index suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64599392/1319004) and together with this one:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` ADD INDEX `status_type` (`post_status`, `post_type`);
```

Helped to bring cca. 20s meta post queries to virtually instant (my SQL client says `0.0001 seconds`).

The lesson is that you have to look at your slow queries, what columns and tables they work with, in what way are they joined and attempt to help the db to perform well on those particular queries by composite indexes (for correlated criteria) and even foreign keys (for joins).